# Google fit API quotas and limitation

Tags: google-fit

Is there a quotas and request limitation when using google fit api? I want to use the google fit api and I'm curious if there is a limitation when using it.

Answer (score 5):

You may check your project's Fitness API current limit of in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). As I've checked my current project, the default limits are:

- 86,400 Queries per day
- 500 Queries per 100 seconds per user
- 1,000 Queries per 100 seconds

Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You can request more quota limits or view quotas for your other services on the Quotas page, found in IAM & admin.

Comment: Hi, is there a chargeable fee if we want to increase quota limits?